# python sorting objects in a list using to criteria

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of objects that have two attributes `first_name` and `last_name`. I want to be able to sort the names first by the `last_name` and then by `first_name`.

For example, if sorting `John James` and `Andrew James`, I want Andrew first and John second. I followed [this](http://goo.gl/egWLSE) and used the `sort` function

```
try:
    import operator
    except:
        cmpkey = lambda x: x.last_name
        cmpkey2 = lambda x: x.first_name
    else:
        cmpkey = operator.attrgetter('last_name')
        cmpkey2 = operator.attrgetter('first_name')

    search_result.sort(key=cmpkey, reverse=False)
    search_result.sort(key=cmpkey2, reverse=False)
```

But when I have two objects like the following

1. Nikos Galis
2. Nigel Reynolds

If I use the code above it shows Nigel first (because Nigel comes before Nikos) which is not what I wanted. I guess the above code would work in the case that when we have the same last_name in both objects, but It doesn't work as I want to when the objects are different. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sort just once and return a *tuple*:

```
search_result.sort(key=lambda x: (x.last_name, x.first_name))
```

Tuples are lexicographically; if the first elements are equal, order is determined by the second elements, etc.

You can replace the `lambda` with [`operator.attrgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) and give it multiple attributes to build a tuple from:

```
from operator import attrgetter

search_result.sort(key=attrgetter('last_name', 'first_name'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Person = namedtuple('Person', 'first_name last_name')
>>> search_result = [Person('John', 'James'), Person('Andrew', 'James'), Person('Nigel', 'Reynolds'), Person('Nikos', 'Galis')]
>>> search_result.sort(key=lambda x: (x.last_name, x.first_name))
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(search_result)
[Person(first_name='Nikos', last_name='Galis'),
 Person(first_name='Andrew', last_name='James'),
 Person(first_name='John', last_name='James'),
 Person(first_name='Nigel', last_name='Reynolds')]
>>> import random
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> random.shuffle(search_result)
>>> search_result.sort(key=attrgetter('last_name', 'first_name'))
>>> pprint(search_result)
[Person(first_name='Nikos', last_name='Galis'),
 Person(first_name='Andrew', last_name='James'),
 Person(first_name='John', last_name='James'),
 Person(first_name='Nigel', last_name='Reynolds')]
```

Comment: Can i do the same in attgetter..like attrgetter('last_name', 'first_name')?

Comment: @Apostolos: yes, you can.